# What url to use for update function in a resource in Laravel 4 in ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to update a field for a user in my db, and I am trying to do it with ajax.  I have a resource (fans), and in my FansController I have a function update($id):

I use the ajax call like so:

```
var full_name = $("#user_name").val();
var full_location = $("#user_city").val();

request = $.ajax({ 
          url: "http://url.com/fans/update", 
          type: "post", success:function(data){console.log(data);}, 
          data: {'full_name': full_name, 'full_location': full_location} ,beforeSend: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          } 
  });
```

The full_name and full_location are getting pulled fine.  I am not sure if they are being passed to the function correctly though.  The console.logs are logging fine, but they are not showing the correct data in the console (it just prints the entire source).

The update function:

```
public function update($id)
        {

            //get saved info from fan profile
            $full_name = Input::get('full_name');
            $full_location = Input::get('full_location');

            //echo var_dump($full_name);

            $split_name = explode(" ", $full_name);

            $first_name = $split_name[0];

            $i=0;
            foreach ($split_name as $name) {

                if($i > 0) {
                    $last_name = $name[i] + " ";
                }
                $i++;
            }

            $trimmed_last_name = trim($last_name);


            //find user
            $fan = Fan::where('id', '=', $id)->first();

            $fan->first_name = $first_name;
            $fan->last_name = $trimmed_last_name;

            $fan->save();
        }
```

The DB is not updating, so I assume the function isn't being called (even though the ajax is showing a success).  Anything I'm missing?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto your terminal/command prompt and type and run following command:

```
php artisan routes
```

This will return you something like this (Details about all routes declared in your application):

```
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                          |  Name         |  Action                  | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET posts                    | posts.index   | PostController@index     |                |               |
|        | GET posts/c                  | posts.create  | PostController@create    |                |               |
|        | POST posts                   | posts.store   | PostController@store     |                |               |
|        | GET posts/{posts}            | posts.show    | PostController@show      |                |               |
|        | GET posts/{posts}/edit       | posts.edit    | PostController@edit      |                |               |
|        | PUT posts/{posts}            | posts.update  | PostController@update    |                |               |
|        | PATCH posts/{posts}          |               | PostController@update    |                |               |
|        | DELETE posts/{posts}         | posts.destroy | PostController@destroy   |                |               |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

From this result, find out the appropriate `url` to use for the method. In this case, for the `update` method using `PATCH` request `method` you may use something like this:

```
posts/10
```

Since it's a resource controller, you may use something like following:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "fans/10", // 10 is user id to update, for example
    type: "post", 
    data: { full_name:full_name, full_location:full_location, _method:"PATCH" },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

So your `update` method will be matched because, your `update` method looks like this:

```
public function update($id)
{
    //...
}
```

According to your `url` you should have following route (resourceful) declared:

```
Route::resource('fans', 'FansController');
```

If you are keeping your `JS` code in a seoarate file then you may also check [this article](http://heera.it/laravel-pass-user-object-javascript-object#.Uz983_mSySo), it's about how to send a model object from server to client side (as `JavaScript` Object), would be helpful to get the idea about to send the `id` from server to client, so you may able to use the `id` in your `JS` function.

Comment: but if I use fans/10, how does it know to use the update function, and not the show function?

Comment: Becaue it's a `resource` controller and it knows how to do it.

Comment: Ok, well I tried it using that url with "put", and I am getting an internal service error.  And when I use "post" it is still not working...Not sure why it's not passing the data to the function.

Comment: I've used `PATCH` method not `PUT`.

Comment: Also, to make sure it's going to `update` method try this `dd($id)` inside the method.

Comment: hmm, it seems that it's rerouting to another one of my routes "/fans/landing"...it is running in the update function, but dd($id) returns: string(7) "landing".  I do have this construct in my fanscontroller: public function __construct()
        {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only' => array('show', 'update')));
        }

Without the update function in there though, it gives me the internal server error...

Comment: Got it, I needed one more slash: /fans/{{$fan->id}} as opposed to fan/{{$fan->id}}.  Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

your not passing the $id to the controller function

```
$fan = Fan::where('id', $id)->first(); 
same as
$fan = Fan::find($id);
```

these will not return anything because $id isn't set.

Also you are not posting back any data that designates which Fan you are updating, like an id.

UPDATE:

If you are going to pass the id back through the post:

```
public function update() {
    $id  = Input::get('id');
    $fan = Fan::find($id);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am now passing back the id as well, and it is still not updating the resource in the table.

Comment: what does your route look like

Comment: Route::resource('fans', 'FansController');

Comment: Didn't know you were using resource
change your method to PUT instead of POST

Comment: I get an error when I use put: PUT http://url.com/fans/update 500 (Internal Server Error)